# Daterangepicker how can i get the value of predefined date range

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get the value of my predefined daterange of my `daterangepicker`

I try to use `.val()` and `.text()` but not working please see code below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($('#reportrange').find(":selected").val());
});
$(function() {

  var start = moment().subtract(6, 'days');
  var end = moment();

  function cb(start, end) {
    $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
  }

  $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    ranges: {
      'Today': [moment(), moment()],
      'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
      'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
      'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
      'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
      'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    }
  }, cb);

  cb(start, end);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="sel1">Date:</label>
  <div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc;">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason, why you getting undefined is `$(document).ready` and $`(function() {` do run at same time and because of that, your daterangepicker may not be properly declared at that time.
So, if you want to get the values, you can have them in callback function.

Matter of fact,

> daterangepicker startDate and endDate returns moment objects not
>   Javascript Date objects.

```js
$(function() {

  var start = moment().subtract(6, 'days');
  var end = moment();
 var lstart,lend;
  function cb(start, end) {
    $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
       lstart = moment($('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').startDate).toDate(),
       lend = moment($('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').endDate).toDate();
       console.log(lstart,lend)
  }

  $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    ranges: {
      'Today': [moment(), moment()],
      'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
      'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
      'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
      'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
      'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    }
  }, cb);

  cb(start, end);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js">
</script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="sel1">Date:</label>
  <div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc;">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, From moment, you can get date in any format.
Here is the [fiddlelink](https://jsfiddle.net/vikasguptaa9/wbgxnqc5/)

Comment: Thank you , it works! I only needed the `moment($('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').startDate).toDate()` and `moment($('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').endDate).toDate()` to call it from another function!

Comment: I have a question, how can i use the run a function in my `reportrange`, onchange is not working

Answer (score 1):

First you fill date on page load than you will get it.
Try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

          var start = moment().subtract(6, 'days');
          var end = moment();

          function cb(start, end) {
            $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
          }

          $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
            startDate: start,
            endDate: end,
            ranges: {
              'Today': [moment(), moment()],
              'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
              'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
              'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
              'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
              'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
            }
          }, cb);

          cb(start, end);


        //get date_range  
        var date = $('#reportrange > span').text();
        alert(date);

});
```